# Mysqli query is not returning anything when attempting to filter duplicate times on the same day

Tags: php, mysqli

I have attempted multiple ways to do this and I am just at wits end.
I am trying to check for overlapping times on a specific date from a aircraft reservation calendar.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="add-schedule.php" method="post">
            Aircraft:<BR>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET["air"]; ?>" name="aircraft" readonly><BR><BR>
            Pilot in Command:<BR>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="user" readonly><BR><BR>
            Date:<BR>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET["dt"])); ?>" name="dt" readonly><BR><BR>
            Start Time:<BR>
            <input type="time" name="tm" required><BR><BR>
            End Time:<BR>
            <input type="time" name="et" required><BR><BR>
            <input type="submit"><BR><BR>
            </form><BR>
```

Here is my add file:

```
    <?php
    include('connect.php');

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['aircraft']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
    $dt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dt']);
    $tm = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tm']);
    $et = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['et']);
    $TM = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tm));
    $ET = date('H:i:s', strtotime($et));

    if ($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM cal WHERE ( '$TM' BETWEEN cal_time 
AND cal_end) OR ('$ET' BETWEEN cal_time AND cal_end) OR (cal_time < '$TM' 
AND cal_end > '$ET') AND cal_date = '$dt' AND cal_air = '$name'"))
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {

            header("location:add-sched-error.php");
        }

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cal (cal_air, cal_user, cal_date, cal_time, cal_end) 
    VALUES('$name', '$user', '$dt', '$tm', '$et')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header("location:aircraft-schedule.php");

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

What am I missing here?

***EDIT***
edited OP to make question more clear. (removed var_dump results)

Comment: Use prepared statements if at all possible.

Comment: To analyze your code print your builded sql code to screen and run it on a mysql manager to see what could it be wrong. if you get results then probably you've a typo somewhere.

Comment: The `NULL` value might be because you're trying to var_dump `$results` while the variable is actually called `$result`

Comment: prepared statements are not needed here. I only execute the statement once.

Comment: @rickdenhaan well the var_dump was just an attempt to see the problem anyway. Thats not the actual issue.

Comment: @Jimistrator Then your question is unclear, please elaborate. According to the title, you're getting a NULL result from your query. That's not true, you're looking at a variable that doesn't exist. The fact that your other variables are echo'd means you're entering the `if` condition, so `$result` cannot be NULL.

Comment: @rickdenhaan ok since its not helping I removed it. I also removed the commented out part to show it in its original form. Also I removed the "." on each side of the strings as it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing around with your code and a test database, it pretty much works except for your combination of `OR` and `AND` in the `SELECT` query. Wrapping the time check in an extra set of parentheses worked for me:

```
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM cal WHERE ( ( '$TM' BETWEEN cal_time 
AND cal_end) OR ('$ET' BETWEEN cal_time AND cal_end) OR (cal_time < '$TM' 
AND cal_end > '$ET') ) AND cal_date = '$dt' AND cal_air = '$name'"))
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

        header("location:add-sched-error.php");
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope, this didnt work for me. I have a DB entry of same day with start time if 8am to 9am then when I use the form and enter another reservation at 8:01 to 9:00 am it doesnt catch it.

Comment: That's odd, because the `'$TM' BETWEEN cal_time AND cal_end` should catch that (assuming it's also the same aircraft): `SELECT ('08:01:00' BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00');` returns `1` (or true) for me. If you print the query with all variables filled, does it look right?

Comment: I was playing with it alittle at work today and it catches them sometimes. Its almost like either the db or php isnt liking the format the times are in and its not seeing a match in the query.

Comment: OK so what if you try a different approach? This condition should also catch all overlaps: `'$TM' <= cal_end AND '$ET' >= cal_time` (assumes an aircraft reservation start time may equal the end time of a previous reservation for that aircraft, switch to `<` and `>` if that's not allowed)

Comment: I tried it that way early on. I will try it again though. I feel like the problem is related to when the info is entered in the form. I use the php5 "time" form type of box and they display differently depending on what browser you use. I try combating this by doing a "$TM = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tm));" to the $_POST after its escaped. Maybe I shouldnt use the strtotime?

Comment: Well, how the input is rendered in the browser is different from how the value is submitted to the server. Maybe you don't need to convert it at all?

Comment: whats really strange is it catches every time it I go back and edit an entry, leave the overlapped time in the box and submit. It catches it...

Comment: That's interesting. Are those entries different from the pre-existing entries in the database?

Comment: Well I dont know if you ever used a one of the time entry boxes from php5 but you can type in either 6:00 pm or 1800 in the box and it comes out as 24hr or 1800. so thats why I added this: $TM = date('H:i:s', strtotime($tm)); which makes it match like the db stores it with the 18:00:00. The edit entry file is exactly the same as new entry one other than its pulling from the db for the times instead of a form.

Comment: Since it works once the times already in the db I am going to try letting a new entry be added to the db then run code to do the check after the fact and delete duplicate maybe, I dont know.